# LINQ Entity Framework Select into a non-primary-key relationship

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework

i have a 3 class models with overlapping relationships:

```
class worder {
  int workerID
}    
class shift {
  int shiftID,
  int workerID,
  ICollection tasks //tasks for this shift and this worker
}
class task {
  int workerID
  int shiftID
}
```

how do i populate a collection of shift objects that include its respective .tasks?  something like:

```
var q = from shift in db.shifts
  .Include(s => s.tasks.Where(t=>t.shiftID == s.shiftID && t.workerID = s.workerID))
```

EDIT

I have successfully used an projection to create an anonymous type as suggested by jethro.  but i would like to return strongly typed shift classes instead.  is that possible?  or a poor design of the shift model?

Comment: Did you use "Code First" approach, or Design from database with EF? Are you classes based on tables in your database, and do they have a relationship?

Comment: what's the relationship between `shift` and `task` in your model? Ideally you shouldn't have to do anything and just use the `tasks` property if modeled correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join the tables.

```
var joinedTables = from c in db.shifts
                   join p in db.tasks on c.ShiftID equals p.ShiftID & c.WorkerID equals p.WorkerID
select new {Shifts = c, Tasks = p };
```

Please check this [Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/ee908647#crossjoin) for additional examples on Linq Joins.

```
var shifts = db.shifts;
var tasks = db.tasks;

foreach(var shift in shifts)
{
    var shiftID = shift.ShiftID;
    var workerID = shift.WorkerID;
    shift.tasks = tasks.Where(p=>p.shiftID == shiftID & p.WorkerID == workerID);
}
```

Something about the above feels "not right" to me, I think it would be best if you look at your design again, the tasks of the shifts should be populated automatically when you pull the shifts.

Comment: 1. i am using Code First.  there is no direct relationship between shift and tasks.  the shift.tasks collection should contain a subset of tasks that relate to the shift by both shiftID and workerID

Comment: i understand your suggestion and have done that.  is there any way to return strongly typed shift objects instead?

Comment: If you just select from db.shifts does it not return the list of tasks?

Comment: im not sure i fully understand your question, but shifts.tasks returns empty because entity framework cannot discover the relationship from the class definition.  and i do not know how to explicitly request it using linq.  i thought my linq query above would work but it did not.

Comment: your second example, assigning the shift.tasks property directly in a foreach loop, looks like it could work for me.  so i suppose the answer is that i cannot accomplish the goal using a single linq statement.  i need to create linq subqueries and then execute them within a foreach.  let me know if you agree.  thanks